# Why can't I see inserted data in my view / tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Firstly I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "DEPTT_DEMO1" 
(   
    "DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "DEPARTMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "DEPT_NAME_NN1" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
    CONSTRAINT "DEPT_ID_PK1" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
);
```

After the table is created, I insert a few rows of data and then created a view like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dept_demo_vw1 
AS
     SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID, DEPARTMENT_NAME, MANAGER_ID, LOCATION_ID 
     FROM DEPTT_DEMO1;
```

I create a trigger as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER vw_dept_tri 
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON dept_demo_vw1
--declare
BEGIN
    UPDATE dept_demo_vw1 
    SET DEPARTMENT_ID = dept_id.nextval 
    WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IS NULL;
END vw_dept_tri;
```

After this when I try to insert data into the view, it says that the data is inserted, but I can't see any data in my view.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what you are doing, but you're doing it wrong.

- `INSTEAD OF` trigger you wrote doesn't make much sense. It is *instead of* `INSERT`, but you are performing an `UPDATE`
- Moreover, you are updating a **view**, but you should have been doing it on a **table** (not a view); that's why it is called "instead of" - instead of inserting into a view, you'd be inserting into a table
- `DEPTT_DEMO1.DEPARTMENT_ID` is a primary key column. It means that it can not accept `NULL` values
- Trigger's `WHERE` clause says `WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IS NULL`; it is **never** NULL, that's a primary key column

Shortly, you'll have to think it over and do it properly.